# dateByAddingComponents method error

Tags: xcode4.5

Using NSCalendar and its method `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` the method sometimes return a wrong value. For instante:

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setYear:2013];
    [components setMonth:2];
    [components setDay:27];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2013-02-27

    NSDateComponents *addingComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [addingComponents setMonth:1];
    [addingComponents setDay:4]; // value 5 give the same result.
    date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:addingComponents toDate:date options:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2013-03-31
```

The console `log: 2013-02-27 and 2013-03-31`.

Now, if a change the day component value to 5, the method return the same `NSDate`, but if a change to 6, the date if 2013-04-01.

Anyone has an answer for this behavior? Thanks on advance.

Rafael Cruz Márquez.